# SQL: selecting specific records in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance, query-performance

Suppose I have a table of customers and a table of purchases.

Customers can have multiple purchases. Some times customers have old purchases as well feature purchases.

In that case I need to show latest old purchases. If a customer has only feature purchase I should show that one.

I wrote query but I think we can improve What is the best practice? Any advice on this query?

Consider these tables:

- customer: id, name
- purchase: id, customer_id, item_id, effective_from_date

**Query**

```
SELECT c.*, p.*
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN purchase p
ON p.id =
(IF((SELECT Count(*) FROM purchase p1 WHERE  p1.customer_id = c.id) <= 1,
(SELECT p2.id FROM   purchase p2 WHERE  p2.customer_id = c.id),
(SELECT p3.id FROM purchase p3 WHERE p3.customer_id=c.id AND
p3.effective_from_date < now() 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)))
```

Comment: sort the purchase table by date in descending order and put max result of one or how many records you want. like
SELECT column1,column2 FROM table LIMIT count;

Comment: Can `effective_from_date` be in the future?  What determines "feature purchase"?